# Proof of general Knaster-Tarski fixpoint theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

Prove that the set of fixed points $Fix(f)$ of an order-preserving operator $f$ on a complete lattice
$(L, \sqsubseteq)$ is a complete lattice itself. **Moreover, show that $\mathrm{Fix}(f)$ is a complete sublattice of $L$**.

The first part of this statement is known as Knaster-Tarski theorem. Can you please give some hints on how to prove it in a straight-forward way?
I think it is sufficient to prove the existence of a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound of any subset of $Fix(f)$.

Moreover, I haven't found anything online about proving that $Fix(f)$ is a complete sublattice of $L$. How would you prove it? Thank you in advance.
I'm a CS graduate trying to wrap my head around abstract semantics of programming languages.

Here are some useful definitions (feel free to correct them in case of errors):

**Upper Bound**
Given a subset $X \subseteq L$, $l \in X$ is an *upper bound* if $\forall\ l' \in X : l' \sqsubseteq l$. A *least upper bound* (also called *supremum*) $l \in X$ is an upper bound of $X$ that satisfies $l \sqsubseteq l_0$ whenever $l_0$ is another upper bound of $X$.

**Lower Bound**
Given a subset $X \subseteq L$, $l \in X$ is a *lower bound* if $\forall\ l' \in X : l' \sqsupseteq l$. A *greatest lower bound* (also called *infimum*) $l \in X$ is a lower bound of $X$ that satisfies $l_0 \sqsubseteq l$ whenever $l_0$ is another lower bound of $X$.

**Complete Lattice**: A complete lattice $L = (L, \sqsubseteq) = (L, \sqsubseteq, \sqcup, \sqcap, \top, \bot)$ is a partially ordered set $(L, \sqsubseteq)$ such that all subsets of $L$ have least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds.

**Sublattice**: Let $L = (L, \sqsubseteq)$ be a lattice.
$S \subseteq L$ is a sublattice of $L$ if and only if

\begin{equation*}
    \forall x, y \in S\ :\ x \sqcup y \in S\ \wedge\ x \sqcap y \in S 
\end{equation*}

**Order-preserving Operator**:
An operator $f : L \rightarrow L$ on a partially ordered set $(L, \sqsubseteq)$ is *order-preserving* if

\begin{equation}
    \forall\ l, l' \in L : l \sqsubseteq l' \Rightarrow f(l) \sqsubseteq f(l')
\end{equation}

**Fixed point**: Given an order-preserving operator $f : L \rightarrow L$ defined on a complete lattice $(L, \sqsubseteq)$, a *fixed point* of $f$ is an element $l \in L$ such that $f(l) = l$. The set of all fixed points is

\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{Fix}(f) = \{ l\ |\ f(l) = l \} 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

I don't think $Fix(f)$ is a complete sublattice of $L$.
Maybe you're missing some additional condition, or maybe I'm thinking wrong.
Check the following and let me know!

Let $L = \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N) \cup \{\mathbb N, \mathbb Q\}$, where $\wp_{fin}(X)$ denotes the family of finite subsets of $X$, and $L$ is ordered by set inclusion.
This is a complete lattice.

Define $f:L\to L$ by making
$$
x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
x, &\text{ if } x \in \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N),\\
\mathbb{Q}, &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is order-preserving, but $Fix(f) = \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N) \cup \{\mathbb Q\} = L\setminus\{\mathbb N\}$ is not a complete sublattice of $L$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that function $f$ really does not seem order-preserving to me, and I'm sure that $Fix(f)$ is a complete sublattice of $L$.

Comment: @AlbertoSchiabel If you think that $f$ is not order-preserving, please give an example of a pair $a,b \in L$ with $a \leq b$ but $f(a) \nleq f(b)$.

Comment: It is not true that $L$ in the provided answer is a complete lattice. For example, for any natural number $m\geq2$ we have $\bigcup \{\{n\}|n\equiv 0 \text{ mod } m\}\not\in L$.

Comment: @MichaelCromberge That's right. However, the join in this lattice is not given by set union. The join of the set you mentioned is the set $\mathbb N$. How is this? Well, it's the least upper bound, right?

Comment: @MichaelCromberge And you can check that a lattice is complete in another way: It's enough that there exist meets of all subsets (and yes, here meets are given by set intersection). More generally, a lattice $L$ is complete iff for all $A \subseteq L$, there exists $\bigwedge A$ in $L$, iff for all $A \subseteq L$, there exists $\bigvee A$ in $L$.

Comment: Hi amrsa, thank you for your correction, my apologies, I was wrong to state arbitrary join is union in this case. I also see now that $L\setminus \{\mathbb{N}\}$ is a complete lattice but not a sublattice of L. I agree then that it appears the OPs statement of the Knaster-Tarski theorem needs to be revised. Also, the versions of it I have seen don't stipulate the set of fixed points to be a sub-lattice. Finally, I also agree that $f$ is an increasing map.

Comment: @MichaelCromberge You're welcome. But notice that $L\setminus\{\mathbb N\}$ is a sub-lattice of $L$, it's just not a *complete* sub-lattice. In general, $Fix(f)$ is a sub-lattice of $L$, but not necessarily a complete sub-lattice, as this counter-example shows.

Comment: @MichaelCromberge A correction to an earlier comment: in this lattice, the join of every finite sub-set is given by union; it's the join of infinitely many elements that is not necessarily so.

Comment: @amrsa, I might be missing something but it appears $L\setminus {\mathbb{N}}$ is a complete lattice as it is closed under arbitrary joins. Also, if this were not the case then we surely would be violating the [K-T theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TarskisFixedPointTheorem.html)? 
I said $L\setminus\mathbb{N}$ isn't a sub-lattice of $L$ as the joins on the two lattices don't agree (e.g. consider the set of singletons described in my first comment). 
Thank you for your correction, I understood that you were referring to infinite joins.

Comment: @MichaelCromberge It is a sub-lattice and it is a complete lattice on its own, but not a complete sub-lattice. In $L$, the join of the finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is $\mathbb N$; in $L\setminus\{\mathbb N\}$, it is $\mathbb Q$. It's still a sub-lattice because the join (or meet) of any pair of elements from $L\setminus\{\mathbb N\}$ is the same as in $L$.

Comment: Apologies @amrsa, I thought sub-lattice implied all joins, meets (finite and infinite) exist and agree with those in the containing lattice. I now see that this is rather describing a *complete sub-lattice* of $L$. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\operatorname{Fix}(f)$ may not even be a sublattice of $L$. Take $L$ to be the lattice $\{\bot,a,a',b,\top\}$ where $$\bot<a,a'<b<\top$$ and $a,a'$ are not comparable and let $f$ be the map such that $$\operatorname{Fix}(f)=L\setminus\{b\}$$ and $$f(b)=\top.$$ The map $f$ is obviously an order-preserving operator. The subset $\operatorname{Fix}(f)$ with order inherited from $L$ is a (complete) lattice on its own, isomorphic to the square of the two-point lattice. (Since the underlying set of the lattice is finite it is complete just by being a lattice.) It fails to be a complete sublattice, or a sublattice because the join of the two elements $a,a'$ differs in $\operatorname{Fix}(f)$ and $L$, which is $\top$ and $b$, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of $\text{Fix}(f)$ not being a complete sublattice of $f$, even when $L$ is totally ordered.

Let $L = [0, 2]$, $f:L\to L$ be defined as $f(x) = x$ for $x\in [0, 1)$ and $f(x) = 2$ for $x\in [1, 2]$.

Then $\text{Fix}(f) = [0, 1)\cup \{2\}\subseteq [0, 2]$ is not a complete sublattice of $[0, 2]$, but $\text{Fix}(f)\cong [0, 1]$ as an ordered set. Note that $\text{Fix}(f)$ is a sublattice of $L$ since $L$ is totally ordered (hence $f$ preserves finite joins and meets).

Note that a totally ordered space $X$ is a complete lattice iff its compact. The example above shows that $\text{Fix}(f)$ is compact as a totally ordered space, but not necessarily as a subspace of $X$.